# AndroidStudio EditText issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, edit

I have an issue when i use EditText in AndroidStudio. When i try to get theEditText result, i get this :

> System.out: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{604b1c5 VFED..CL. .F...... 81,154-1032,290 #7f0c0083 app:id/editText}

and my code is

```
TextView passwordDisplay = (TextView)         
editText_pswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
pswd = editText_pswd.getText().toString();
System.out.println(editText_pswd);
```

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Post xml code and add more code to understand issue.

Comment: Post full activity code.

Comment: You do not need to post the entire activity, but you should at least post code which compiles. This means you should have a line like `public class MyActivty extends Activity` and another line like `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` along with appropriate curly braces. Also, the first line of code shown here is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the `editText_pswd` object, which is an `EditText`, not a `String`.

```
System.out.println(editText_pswd);
```

This rarely provides useful information. Instead, you need to print the text from the `EditText`:

```
 System.out.println(pswd);
```